# tomcat - solaris getRequestURI() returns a partially decoded uri

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, request, solaris

I have some code running on my dev machine a regular mac running tomcat and 
        `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()`
returns a fully encoded uri.

However in Solaris running apache-tomcat-7.0.32 (same version as my dev machine) 
I see decoded commas "," and parenthesis "(" , ")" as opposed to encoded the rest of the String thats returned. In Other words the `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` gives me a partial encoded value.

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Is there another web server sitting in front of the tomcat on solaris (e.g. apache httpd), or are you connecting to the tomcat directly in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the version of Tomcat/Java that we were using in Solaris. Updating seemed to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Well as per the spec , the web container will not decode the URI.
In other words if the URL is encoded/or not it will be displayed as it is

```
  String getRequestURI()

        Returns the part of this request's URL from the protocol name up to the query string in the first line of the HTTP request. The web container does not decode this String. For example:
        First line of HTTP request  Returned Value
        POST /some/path.html HTTP/1.1       /some/path.html
        GET http://foo.bar/a.html HTTP/1.0      /a.html
        HEAD /xyz?a=b HTTP/1.1      /xyz
```

**Reference:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29